# i have made a search button with following functionality:

Tags: python, tkinter, mysql-workbench

```
def search(self):
    conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",username="root",password="krish@123",database="face_monitoring") 
    mycursor=conn.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("select * from room where"+str(self.search_var.get())+" LIKE '%"+str(self.txt_search.get())+"%'")
    rows=mycursor.fetchall()
    if len(rows)!=0:
        self.room_details.delete(*self.room_details.get_children())
        for i in rows:
            self.room_details.insert("",END,values=i)
        conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

error:

mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Name LIKE '%krishna mishra%'' at line 1

Comment: I think this is purely an SQL question. If so, please remove the `tkinter` tag. Also shouldn't there be a space at the end of `"select * from room where"` so it becomes `"select * from room where "`?

Comment: I have done that but it didn't corrected that thing